# How to map an extra mouse button to ctrl z?

Tags: shortcut

Around 50% of my key presses consist ctrl+z.

How can I map ctrl+z to my mx mouse's thumb extra button in Linux?

Pressing the button in `preferences > Undo` has no effect, while it works out of the box in Firefox (history back).

Env: ArchLinux

Answer (score 1):

What you need is your mouse's software installed. For example, Logitech has its own software for its peripherals like keyboard, mouse.

Once installed, open up the program, and set your extra key as CTRL+Z